# Jmeter - Run Requests inside the thread consecutively and not at the same time

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

How to Run Requests inside the thread **consecutively** and not at the same time using Jmeter(one by one). I want to achieve the following one at a time.

```
Thread 1 - Create Product

Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product
Create Product

Thread 2 - Get Product by Id

Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id
Get Product By Id

Thread 3 - Get All Products

Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
Get Products
```

I have realized i am using a very bad method how can i achieve this? This is what i have done:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion is configure a TG using ONE thread, and use a loop (within the TG) to consecutively execute the requests whatever requests you need.

Comment: TG? Thread group? yes but if i use the loop then it will run one request with 10 users. it is not that same

Comment: As mentioned, the Thread Group (TG) will be configured for only *ONE* VUser or thread, which will execute the 10 requests sequentially within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

By default each JMeter thread (virtual user) runs [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) consecutively (upside down) so you don't really need to do anything in order to achieve the desired behaviour.

If you want 2nd thread group to run after first thread group, 3rd thread group after 2nd, etc. just tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level:

[image]

Also you might want to consider [parameterizing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) your test plan using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so you won't have to copy and paste the requests but rather provide different values from an external source for each virtual user/iteration

Comment: I think you are not understanding my point. I want to run each request inside the thread also one by one. Can i use a loop controller in that case?

Comment: I think you cannot read/understand English, each thread executes samplers upside down and **one by one**.

Comment: i see sorry for the misunderstanding. Can i also achieve the same behaviour with the loop count on the thread level? without having to use CSV data set config or without having to copy and paste requests?

Comment: Each thread will execute samplers consecutively no matter how many loops you have, one or infinite number

Comment: yes thank you i got it but can i use a loop count instead of using CSV data set config to duplicated the requests? so lets say i need to run 10 samplers in each thread, cant i just make the loop count to 10?